# How to know when a fetch ends without locking the body stream?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, whatwg-streams-api

I'm making requests to an API, but their server only allows a certain number of active connections, so I would like to limit the number of ongoing fetches. For my purposes, a fetch is only completed (not ongoing) when the HTTP response body arrives at the client.

I would like to create an abstraction like this:

```js
const fetchLimiter = new FetchLimiter(maxConnections);
fetchLimiter.fetch(url, options); // Returns the same thing as fetch()
```

This would make things a lot simpler, but there seems to be no way of knowing when a stream being used by other code ends, because streams are locked while they are being read. It is possible to use `ReadableStream.tee()` to split the stream into two, use one and return the other to the caller (possibly also constructing a `Response` with it), but this would degrade performance, right?

Comment: You could just construct a fake `Response` to your caller where you control the stream that the caller will use.

Comment: @Bergi And then pipe the real stream into it? Sounds like a good idea, but I'm not sure about the performance impact of that.

Comment: I'm pretty certain performance of that would be better than `tee()`ing the stream or even `clone()`ing the response. But sure, you'd have to benchmark if you care enough.

Comment: An alternative would be to just pass a callback function to `fetchLimiter` that should process the response, and whose result is awaited for queueing. This is a pretty standard approach for dealing with asynchronous "resource" usage.

Answer (score 2):

Since `fetch` uses promises, you can take advantage of that to make a simple queue system.

This is a method I've used before for queuing promise based stuff. It enqueues items by creating a `Promise` and then adding its resolver to an array. Of course until that Promise resolves, the `await` keeps any later promises from being invoked.

And all we have to do to start the next fetch when one finishes is just grab the next resolver and invoke it. The promise resolves, and then the `fetch` starts!

Best part, since we don't actually consume the `fetch` result, there's no worries about having to `clone` or anything...we just pass it on intact, so that you can consume it in a later `then` or something.

***Edit:** since the body is still streaming after the fetch promise resolves, I added a third option so that you can pass in the body type, and have FetchLimiter retrieve and parse the body for you.

> These all return a promise that is eventually resolved with the actual content.

That way you can just have FetchLimiter parse the body for you. I made it so it would return an array of `[response, data]`, that way you can still check things like the response code, headers, etc.

For that matter, you could even pass in a callback or something to use in that `await` if you needed to do something more complex, like different methods of parsing the body depending on response code.

**Example**

I added comments to indicate where the `FetchLimiter` code begins and ends...the rest is just demo code.

It's using a fake `fetch` using a setTimeout, which will resolve between 0.5-1.5 secs. It will start the first three requests immediately, and then the actives will be full, and it will wait for one to resolve.

When that happens, you'll see the comment that the promise has resolved, then the next promise in the queue will start, and then you'll see the `then` from in the `for` loop resolve. I added that `then` just so you could see the order of events.

```js
(function() {
  const fetch = (resource, init) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('starting ' + resource);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(' - resolving ' + resource);
      resolve(resource);
    }, 500 + 1000 * Math.random());
  });

  function FetchLimiter() {
    this.queue = [];
    this.active = 0;
    this.maxActive = 3;
    this.fetchFn = fetch;
  }
  FetchLimiter.prototype.fetch = async function(resource, init, respType) {
    // if at max active, enqueue the next request by adding a promise
    // ahead of it, and putting the resolver in the "queue" array.
    if (this.active >= this.maxActive) {
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        this.queue.push(resolve); // push, adds to end of array
      });
    }
    this.active++; // increment active once we're about to start the fetch
    const resp = await this.fetchFn(resource, init);
    let data;
    if (['arrayBuffer', 'blob', 'json', 'text', 'formData'].indexOf(respType) >= 0)
      data = await resp[respType]();
    this.active--; // decrement active once fetch is done
    this.checkQueue(); // time to start the next fetch from queue
    return [resp, data]; // return value from fetch
  };

  FetchLimiter.prototype.checkQueue = function() {
    if (this.active < this.maxActive && this.queue.length) {
      // shfit, pulls from start of array. This gives first in, first out.
      const next = this.queue.shift();
      next('resolved'); // resolve promise, value doesn't matter
    }
  }

  const limiter = new FetchLimiter();
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    limiter.fetch('/mypage/' + i)
      .then(x => console.log(' - .then ' + x));
  }
})();
```

**Caveats:**

- I'm not 100% sure if the body is still streaming when the promise resolves...that seems to be a concern for you. However if that's a problem you could use one of the Body mixin methods like `blob` or `text` or `json`, which doesn't resolve until the body content is completely parsed ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body))
- I intentionally kept it very short (like 15 lines of actual code) as a very simple proof of concept. You'd want to add some error handling in production code, so that if the `fetch` rejects because of a connection error or something that you still decrement the active counter and start the next `fetch`.
- Of course it's also using `async/await` syntax, because it's so much easier to read. If you need to support older browsers, you'd want to rewrite with Promises or transpile with babel or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't solve the problem. "I'm not 100% sure if the body is still streaming when the promise resolves..." It is, unless the body is empty or really small. The promise returned by `fetch()` resolves as soon as the headers arrive. "However if that's a problem you could use one of the Body mixin methods like `blob` or `text` or `json`, which doesn't resolve until the body content is completely parsed" That's the problem, because they can't be called more than once.

Comment: I edited my answer. Won't you be calling one of the methods to parse the body at some point anyway? If so, why not just incorporate that call into FetchLimiter, using one of the methods I suggested above. Then just return the parsed body data along with the response, as above.